# is this mold on my kimchi or yeast?

Tags: yeast, fermentation, mold, kimchi

I have been fermenting this kimchi for a month now and it has grown this white things above. I've stored it in in my refridgerator and I only opened it now.  Is this poisonous and should I just throw it out or should i just remove the top?

It doesn't smell rotten or have any foul odor.

[image]

Answer (score 8):

That looks like mould (mold). Kimchi typically only goes mouldy when the vegetables are not submerged, which looks like is happening here, probably because of your choice of container. Use a deeper container like a jar so that all the solids are submerged in the liquid, and continually pack them down so they do not dry out. Alternatively, use a pickling weight or even just a clean pebble. The mould here looks extensive enough to have contaminated the whole container, so you should not eat any of it and throw it away, unfortunately.